# vSphere 5.5 guests are consuming ALL host memory

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I've never had this issue before, but when I was enabling fault tolerance, it seemed to break something and now my guests are consuming ALL of it's memory on the host.

I know with fault tolerance, you need to have the guest reserve all host memory but I have disabled fault tolerance (in the networking section, not sure if there is somewhere else) and it is still consuming all memory.

I have three Windows Server 2012 guests and they are only consuming 81MB, 204MB, and 40MB guest memory. Those three are consuming a total of 11.5GB of host memory...

Usually, they would all consume about 100MB host memory over the guest consumed memory -- and they would share all memory being they are all the same OS.

How come all of these machines are reserving all memory? 
Is there a setting for this somewhere in advanced settings, that enabling fault tolerance and HA enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the data here. The situation you're in has nothing to do with whether or not you have FT enabled.

The "overhead" column you're referencing really has nothing to do with how much memory the **guest** is consuming. Rather, that column indicates the amount of memory that the **hypervisor** requires to power that machine on. The hypervisor uses this "overhead" space to do its own internal bookkeeping for the VM in question.

Unless you want to get into a memory over-subscription situation (not recommended), the "Max" and "Usage" columns are where you want to direct your attention.

Additionally, I'd recommend that you spend a few quality hours going over [this section](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.resmgmt.doc/GUID-2B1086F3-B3F5-426C-9162-3C3CDD23A5DF.html) of VMware's documentation on memory resources.

Comment: Well I enabled FT and in-order to do so and vMotion guests, I was told that you need to reserve all guest memory when doing so. And it seems like the virtual machines are consuming all the host memory. I've had about 5 Windows Server 2008 servers running (months ago for college) and they only consumed about 6GB of memory while all of them had 2GB set.

I'm just confused as to why all of the VMs are reserving all of their memory, which is the 'consumed' column, correct?

Comment: Add up the numbers in your "usage" column. That gets you awfully close to your 11.5GB of host RAM. If they were consuming less that that previously, either you changed configuration or the ballon driver had been invoked to re-claim RAM from one or more of the guests.

Comment: Oh, and you surely **don't** need FT turned on to use vMotion. I'm not sure where you got that information.

Comment: @BillyRowe `I'm just confused as to why all of the VMs are reserving all of their memory, which is the 'consumed' column, correct?` No, the `Consumed` column show's what's consumed.  Look on the far right of your image from RVTools for the `Reservation` column, which is all 0s.

Comment: No, I was playing around with FT and vMotion. But to enable FT, you needed to reserve all guest memory, and I thought vSphere was doing it for me which is why consumed memory is practically all the guest memory.

Comment: Consumed memory is practically all the guest memory because your guests are **using** that memory, which you have allocated them. The shared page functionality *sounds* cool and shiny, but in reality, it's a gimmick. I've never seen any substantial RAM savings from it, and I've run a couple medium-sized VMware clusters, in the 100s of VMs, with a high percentage of identical OS revs, applications, etc.

Comment: @ShaneMadden, I see that -- I didn't reserve any memory -- but why is it consuming all of the 3928MB memory on the physical server, when it is only using 163MB of the guest memory? 

I tried Microsoft Hyper-V, and basically, when the guest is only using 400MB - it only takes 512MB from the physical server. 

vSphere used to do the same thing - I never had to worry about the amount of VMs because it would never hit my 16GB memory limit. It wouldn't even surpass 10GB.

Comment: "when it is only using 163MB of the guest memory"  <- what are you talking about? Have you not understood what we're saying? Look at the **Consumed** column. Your guests are using 3927+2094+4199=10220MB of RAM.

Comment: @BillyRowe As Erik explained, the numbers that are in the hundreds of megabytes in the overhead column in your RVTools report and "Memory Overhead" in vSphere is not being consumed by the VM, or an indicator of what the VM's using in any way - it's how much memory, outside of what's been allocated to the VM, that the hypervisor needs to manage that VM.

Comment: @EEAA - so basically, it says "Okay, you allocated 4GB to me and I will take that all from the host, but I am only using 163MB of that allocated memory."? 

Before, the Windows Server VMs would share a good amount of the memory, and all would be the same. 

Basically, I tried FT and vMotion and now it seems like all of the VMs are consuming too much memory. 

Yes, they are using 10GB of RAM, but not requiring that much. Shouldn't they let go of it when not using it?

Comment: @BillyRowe - where are you getting this 163 number? It's not on your chart.

Comment: Explain this -- why is there even an option to reserve the memory, when in theory, ALL of the guest memory is already (consumed - reserved) from the host?

Comment: @BillyRowe - these are very basic virtualization concepts. I get the feeling that you're new to this and are trying to bone up on your knowledge. The problem is that you're getting out ahead of yourself and making assumptions that are incorrect. Seriously - spend some time reading the documentation I linked to. It explains all of these concepts very clearly.

Comment: @BillyRowe - BTW your assumptions about what a "reservation" means is incorrect.

Comment: @BillyRowe VMs can use less than what they've been allocated through simply not using RAM (though every modern OS will use available RAM as a filesystem cache), as well as the transparent page sharing, ballooning, memory compression, and host swap memory management tools that the ESXi hypervisor uses to manage contention.  A memory reservation ensures that the VM's allocation will be kept in physical RAM instead of being ballooned or compressed or swapped - that's all a reservation is.  And again, where's this 163MB coming from?

Comment: @EEAA I had ESXi for over a year, and just now using vCenter. I did read the memory PDF a few times, and even watched TrainSignal Advanced Networking and some of Performance Monitoring.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Okay, I understand that now!

http://i.imgur.com/2COhG63.png

Comment: @BillyRowe Ahh.  So that "Active" memory is a statistic that shows how much of the VM's physical memory has actually been used recently - it's not an indicator of consumption, it's more an indicator of activity or allocation efficiency - for instance, if a VM isn't actively touching more than 5% of its RAM at a time that might show you that it can have its allocation trimmed down.  See here: https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/10/understanding-vsphere-active-memory.html

Comment: @BillyRowe - in addition to what Shane just mentioned about Active Memory, vSphere also keeps track of that number to help it decide how much RAM it can reclaim from a VM (via the balloon driver) if needed, and if that guest's memory resources are not reserved.

Comment: @ShaneMadden that is kind of what I thought -- I think I am trying to compare Hyper-V to VMware. Hyper-V won't take the full 4GB of the guest memory, but will only use %25 physical memory of the active guest memory. I always thought VMware did the same thing, even better things because they are a virtualization company?

I don't know what is different, but I don't remember ever seeing 'consumed host memory' close to what was allocated.

Comment: CPU usage is low which is good... it's not like I have 2 CPU's allocated and it's using 4.6Ghz of consumed host CPU usage, such as RAM is doing.

I guess I will have to play around a little more and allocate lower. 

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @EEAA so what is with this ballooning driver? This is what I am comparing to with Hyper-V. How can I reclaim unused memory from guests, without adjusting the allocation? Yes, it does this on itself, but why isn't it reclaiming? I'd like to have the full 4 GB in memory because it is an important machine.

Comment: @BillyRowe Read the docs. Seriously. No offense, but this is a site for professionals, and we expect people to be able to do at least a bit of their own research. Once you've researched the balloon driver, by all means, come back here and submit a **new** question about it.

Comment: @EEAA My whole Resume is all of my own research and doing. I learn nothing new in college. I looked it up and trying to see if it's enabled. I'll post a new question if I have any others. 

Thanks.

Comment: @BillyRowe - well then let that research show! Tell us what you've learned and what you're confused by. Tell us how you expect things to work, and how they're not working that way. *That* is how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that they're using what they've been allocated?

It seems extremely unlikely that transparent page sharing is getting you that kind of savings.  Are you certain you're not confusing the memory overhead statistic in vCenter with the consumed RAM?

Can you show us the "Resource Allocation" tab in vCenter for these Windows 2012 VMs using <100 MB of RAM?

Answer (score 0):

All better -- I shut down virtual machines and powered back on and now all memory is being shared. 6 GB utilized instead of close to 11. Ballooning is enabled as well so it will cut back an extra 1 or 2 GB once the virtual machines idle. I knew there was an issue with all memory being consumed and I thought this site would offer some help to the issue.

I'm guessing the automatic virtual machine startup won't balloon and share memory, until the user initiates the boot.

Now, the 4 GB AD machine is only 286MB active and 1405 consumed host memory. That is SO much better than 200MB active and 4 GB consumed.

Now I am happy!

Thanks for trying guys! 
/closed

Comment: You're still confusing things. Memory sharing and ballooning have nothing to do with how machines get started up. Additionally, it is obvious that a machine will consume less RAM immediately after a clean boot. This is due to the fact that it has not built up its page cache yet. Give it a few days of active use, and a guarantee that your VMs memory usage will be right where it was previously.

Comment: Nope. :) My DHCP server is consuming 184MB host memory, and it has been up ever since this old post. There was something wrong when I had posted this - it was consuming more memory than allocated. I guarantee it wasn't normal. I have become more familiar with vSphere, and now up to my VCP5-DCV.:)

Comment: FYI, ballooning doesn't kick in before the host sees severe memory utilisation, around 5% free if I remember correctly, it's an "slight emergency" measure where vmtools start asking the VM OS for memory to map out which pages aren't in use by the VM (if they OS gives a memory pages to the VMTools balloon driver, it's not in use and safe to delete). It's called ballooning because the vmtools ballooning driver "inflates a balloon" in the VM OS memory.